# How to properly cast boost::asio::buffers_iterator as InputIterator

Tags: c++, boost, coverity

I use boost::asio::buffers_iterator in std::string constructor:

```
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::streambuf> receiveBuf;
size_t length = <>; // calculate length
...
std::string message(boost::asio::buffers_begin(receiveBuf->data()),
    boost::asio::buffers_begin(receiveBuf->data()) + length);
```

The code works OK but coverity complains with:

```
(1) Event no_matching_constructor:  no instance of constructor "std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list
(2) Event caretline:    ^
(3) Event argument_list_types_add_on:   argument types are: (boost::asio::buffers_iterator<boost::asio::const_buffers_1, char>, <error-type>)
```

So, I wonder, how to properly cast boost's iterator?

**UPDATE**
After @Caleth pointed at *+ length*, it's turned out to be not so obvious. I must admit that I oversimplified my example code (in order to focus on most relevant part) and so, made it in a wrong way. Sorry for confusion, but for the shown example above coverity is silent. It complains when there is one more piece in the puzzle:

```
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::streambuf> receiveBuf;
size_t length = <>; // calculate length
size_t delimSize = <>; // delimiter size

...
std::string message(boost::asio::buffers_begin(receiveBuf->data()),
    boost::asio::buffers_begin(receiveBuf->data()) + length - delimSize);
```

So, it looks as iterator can be advanced (operator+ overloaded?) but cannot be subtracted (well, code compiles and works, but it's not OK for coverity at least)...

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the expression `boost::asio::buffers_begin(receiveBuf->data()) + length`, which isn't valid.

If `length` means "all the data in the buffer", you want `boost::asio::buffers_end(receiveBuf->data())`.

```
std::string message(boost::asio::buffers_begin(receiveBuf->data()),
    boost::asio::buffers_end(receiveBuf->data()));
```

Otherwise, you will need to fill `message` with something like `std::copy_n`

```
std::string message(length);
std::copy_n(boost::asio::buffers_begin(receiveBuf->data()), length, message.begin());
```

Having a `+` is a feature of [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), which is a much more stringent constraint that [*InputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)

Comment: thank you, I agree about correctness of buffers_begin/end, but take a look at my update, it looks as advancing is legitimate...